# How to customise the tooltip data in react 'recharts'?

Tags: reactjs, graph, momentjs, next.js, recharts

In React application (using Next.js), I am trying to implement graph feature using `recharts` http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart. Right now I am trying to display the date and price value in tooltip, price is displaying properly but date is static for all dots(on hover)

My code is like

/index.js

```
const formatDate = (value) => {
  return moment(value).format('HH:MM A DD MM, YYYY')
}

const weeklyData = [
 { date: formatDate(1613619000), price: '1200.00' },
 { date: formatDate(1613617200), price: '1300.83' },
 { date: formatDate(1613615400), price: '1250.23' },
 { date: formatDate(1613611800), price: '500.55' },
 { date: formatDate(1613608200), price: '1600.23' },
 { date: formatDate(1613606400), price: '1850.93' },
 { date: formatDate(1613604600), price: '1750.23' },
 { date: formatDate(1613599200), price: '650.23' },
]

<LineChart
      width={900}
      height={250}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} cursor={false} />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="price" stroke="#4ec6f4" label="Shruthi" />
</LineChart>
```

/tooltip.js

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    return (
      <div className="tooltip">
       <p className="tooltipLabel">{`$${payload[0].payload?.price}`}</p>
       <p className="tooltipDesc">{`${payload[0]?.payload?.date}`}</p>
      </div>
    )
   }

  return null
}

CustomTooltip.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  payload: PropTypes.array,
  label: PropTypes.string,
}

export default CustomTooltip
```

How can I customise this graph as per my requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by "date is static for all dots"? What's the expected result?

Comment: Question has been updated. Along with price its corresponding date should display but now its displaying only one date for all price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't related to `recharts` but with `moment.js`.

Using [`moment(value)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) expects the value to be in *milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch, but in this case the value you are passing represents *seconds*. Instead, you can use [`moment.unix(value)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) which accepts seconds as intended.

```js
const formatDate = (value) => {
    return moment.unix(value).format('HH:MM A DD MM, YYYY')
}
```

Alternatively, you can still use `moment()` but then you'll have multiply the value you're passing by 1000 so you get milliseconds instead.

```js
const formatDate = (value) => {
    return moment(value * 1000).format('HH:MM A DD MM, YYYY')
}
```

Comment: I am facing UI issue here, If price is more than 1000 then graph will show out of the box(container). If it is less than 1000 then it will show properly within the provided container(box).

Comment: You may consider creating a new question for that issue, in case you need help.

Comment: Created new one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66350379/recharts-how-to-fix-graph-scaling-issue