# Recharts - How to fix graph scaling issue?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, graph, next.js, recharts

In React application (using Next.js), I am trying to implement graph feature using recharts http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart. My code is as below,

/index.js

```
const formatDate = (value) => {
  return moment.unix(value).format('HH:MM A DD MM, YYYY')
}

const weeklyData = [
  { date: formatDate(1613619000), price: '1200.00' },
  { date: formatDate(1613617200), price: '1300.83' },
  { date: formatDate(1613615400), price: '1250.23' },
  { date: formatDate(1613611800), price: '500.55' },
  { date: formatDate(1613608200), price: '1600.23' },
  { date: formatDate(1613606400), price: '1850.93' },
  { date: formatDate(1613604600), price: '1750.23' },
  { date: formatDate(1613599200), price: '650.23' },
]

<LineChart
  width={900}
  height={250}
  data={data}
  margin={{
    top: 5,
    right: 30,
    left: 20,
    bottom: 5,
  }}
>
  <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} cursor={false} />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="price" stroke="#4ec6f4" label="Shruthi" />
</LineChart>
```

/tooltip.js

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
 if (active && payload && payload.length) {
   return (
     <div className="tooltip">
      <p className="tooltipLabel">{`$${payload[0].payload?.price}`}</p>
      <p className="tooltipDesc">{`${payload[0]?.payload?.date}`}</p>
     </div>
   )
  }
  return null
}

CustomTooltip.propTypes = {
 type: PropTypes.string,
 payload: PropTypes.array,
 label: PropTypes.string,
}

export default CustomTooltip
```

Right now `YAxis` is restricted to 1000 and graph(scaling) is displaying out of the box and its invisible.
Graph should be display within the container which I have set.
Here price is not fixed, it can be like `123456.88` or more than this.
In all scenario, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to convert price type to number  or use values without single quotes.

Note: if possible, Post complete code for better response